# Satisfying triples in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, language-agnostic

I'm solving a problem where you have N events (1 <= N <= 100000) over M days (2 <= M <= 10^9). You are trying to find the minimum time of occurrence for each event.

For each event, you know that it couldn't have occurred prior to a day Si. You also have C triples (1 <= C <= 10^5) described by (a, b, x). An event b must have occurred at least x days after a.

Example:

There are 4 events, spread over 10 days. Event 1 had to occur on Day 1 or after. Event 2 had to occur on Day 2 or after. Event 3 had to occur on Day 3 or after. Event 4 had to occur on Day 4 or after.

The triples are (1, 2, 5); (2, 4, 2); (3, 4, 4). This means that Event 2 had to occur at least 5 days after Event 1; Event 4 had to occur at least 2 days after Event 2; and Event 4 had to occur at least 4 days after Event 3.

The solution is that Event 1 occurred on Day 1; Event 2 occurred on Day 6; Event 3 occurred on Day 3; and Event 4 occurred on Day 4. The reasoning behind this is Event 2 occurred at least five days after Event 1, so it cannot have occurred before Day 1+5=6. Event 4 occurred at least two days after Event 2, so it cannot have occurred before Day 6+2=8.

My solution:

I had the idea to use the triples to create a Directed graph. So in the example above, the graph would look like this:

1 --5-> 2 --2-> 4

3 --4-> 4

Basically you create a directed edge from the Event that happened first to the Event that had to happen after. The edge weight would be the number of days it had to at least happen after.

I thought that we could would first use the input data to create the graph. Then, you would just Binary search on all possible starting dates of the first event (1 through 10^9, which is about 30). In this case, the first event is Event 1. Then, you would go through the graph and see if this starting date was possible. If you ever encountered an event where the date it was occurring was before its Si date, then you would terminate this search and continue binary searching. This solution would have worked easy if it wasn't for the "event b must have occurred AT LEAST x days after a".

Does anyone have any other solutions for solving this problem, or how to alter mine so that it works? Thank you! If you have any questions please let me know :))

Comment: If you know the first event, you can try to determine the exact minimum of time that a given event must wait before appearing. For example, if b arrives 2 days after a and 3 days after c, and c arrives 1 day after a, then we know that b cannot arrive before 4 days after a. Such a distance matrix (between all pairs of events = nodes) could by obtained in a iterative way, similar to the Floyd algorithm. Basically, iteratively:`T(x, y) = max (T(x,y), T(x, z) +T(z, y))`

Comment: By applying this method, if there is no solution, it should happen that for some event `x`, `T(x,x) > 0` after some iterations

Comment: Since floyd-warshall is O(N^3), how would I run it with this problem? I do understand your solution though.

Comment: It will have same complexity as Floyd algorithm effectively, which is a problem for a large N value. I think that the recursive relation that I mentioned is the key. In practice, no loop can exist, or it will diverge. The fact that no loop exists should mean that a more efficient algorithm exists

Comment: Do you think you could post some pseudocode for the recursive solution? I think if I could create the recursive solution then I could easily build the graph and do the rest of my solution.

Comment: You might have a look on how to adapt the Dijkstra's algorithm for this context.

Comment: I don't have time just now. Maybe tomorrow. Maybe someone else will do it. Note that I studied such graph algorithms 40 years ago, I need to refresh my memory a little bit. Note also that if you replace T() by -T(), you get a classical min distance problem. And then you need to calculate the min distance from one node to all the others, as you know the start node

Comment: Ok, thank you for everything so far! The idea of making the edges negative is pretty clever, cause then I could run a shortest path algorithm. If I used that to solve my problem, do you think it would work?

Comment: Not sure 100%, to be tested on a simple example

Comment: In your exemple, should not event 4 occur on day 7?
Since ev 3 occurs on day 3 and event 4 occurs at least 4 days after even 3?

Comment: @grodzi Event 2 occurs on day 6, and event 4 has to occur 2 days after event 2.

Comment: oops tricky sequence/ by any chance do you have the challenge link so I can stress test my algo?

Comment: @grodzi I'm sorry I only have the problem on paper :( could you share your algorithm?

Comment: edited my post with code

Comment: This is a problem in an *ongoing* programming contest. By asking others to solve the problems for you like this, you are cheating. Please stop. Anyone reading: please do not help this person cheat. In a few days, the contest will be over and this question will be fair game.

Answer (score 2):

This can be mapped to a **Simple Temporal Network** where literature is rich, e.g.:

- `Dechter, Rina, Itay Meiri, and Judea Pearl. "Temporal constraint networks." Artificial intelligence 49.1-3 (1991): 61-95.`.
- `Planken, Léon Robert. "Algorithms for simple temporal reasoning." (2013).` [full dissertation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.978.8678&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

As indicated in the comments, **all-pairs shortest-paths** can calculate the **minimal-network** (which also generates new arcs/constraints between all these *events*). If your graph is *sparse*, [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) is better than Floyd-Warshall.

If you don't care about the complete minimal-network, but only about the *bounds* of your events, you are only interested in the first column and the first row of the all-pairs shortest-paths distance matrix. You can calculate these values by applying [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) *2*n* times. These values are the distances of `root -> i` and `i -> root` where *root* is time `0`.

Just some remarks about things which Damien indicated (reasoning from scratch it seems: impressive):

- we use negative weights in the general problem such that pure Dijkstra won't do
- existance of negative cycle `<->` infeasibility / no solution / inconsistent
- there will be a need for some *root* vertex which is the *origin of time*

*Edit:* Above somewhat targets *strong inference* / *propagation* like giving *tight bounds* in regards to their *value-domains*.

If you are only interested in *some consistent solution*, it might be another idea just to post these constraints as **linear-program** and use one of the highly-optimized implementations to solve it (open-source world: CoinOR clp; maybe google's glop). Simplex-based ones should give you an integral solution (i think the problem is *totally unimodular*). Interior-point based solvers should be faster, but i'm not sure if your result will be *integral* without some additional need for *cross-over*. (might be a good idea to add some dummy-objective like `min(max(x))` (makespan-like))

Comment: Would Johnson's algorithm run in time, as N could be 10^5?

Comment: Try it (or better BF first). It surely is a *large* number for `O(V^2*E)` asymptotics (iterated BF).

Comment: Do you think Damien's solution would work? I think when I'm scanning the data I'll come up with the root node. Then when I would the graph with negative edge weights and use bellman ford to find the shortest path to every point from the root node. Then I would know the times relative to the first node. Then with the values I could binary search until I get something that works.

Comment: The shortest-paths `root -> i` are the upper-bounds, while the paths `i -> root` are the (negated) lower-bounds of those time-windows. Finding a feasible solution from those is not needing *search* anymore.

Comment: Quite interesting. Just a point: in the Bellman-Ford algorithm, I don't understand why you should calculate the `i -> root` distances, as there should not be any cycle in the graph here. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a [topological sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/) of your DAG.

For a list L corresponding to the toposort of your graph, you have at the end the leaves.
Then for a vertex just before

```
L = [..., v, leaves]
```

you know that the edges outoing from `v` can **only** go to the vertices after (here the `leaves`).
This allows you to compute the minimal weight associated to `v` by applying Damien's max.

Do so up to the head of `L`.

Topological sorting is O(V+E)

---

Here is an illustration with a more interesting graph (read it from top to bottom)

```
    5
   /  \
  4    7
       1 2
       0
       6
```

A topo ordering is (`4601275`)

So we will visit in order `4,6,0,1,2,7` then `5` and any vertex we visit has all its dependencies already computed.

Assume each vertex `k` has event occuring after `2^k` days. The after date is referred as weight.

e.g vertex `4` is weighted `2^4`

Assume each edge `(i,j)` is weighted `5*i + j`

- 6 is weighted `2^6 = 64`
- 0 is weighted `max(2^0, 64 + (0*5+6)) = 70`
- 1 takes `max(2^1, 70 + 5) = 75`
- 7 takes `max(2^7, 75 + 5*7+1, 2^2) = 2^7`

Point to be highlighted (here for `7`) is that the minimal date induced by dependencies of a node may occur before the date attached to that node. (and we have to keep the biggest one)

```js
function topologicalSort({ V, E }) {
  const visited = new Set ()
  const stack = []
  function dfs (v) {
    if (visited.has(v)) { return }
    E.has(v) && E.get(v).forEach(({ to, w }) => dfs(to))
    visited.add(v)
    stack.push(v)
  }
  // process nodes without incoming edges first
  const heads = new Set ([...V])
  for (const v of V) {
    const edges = E.get(v)
    edges && edges.forEach(({ to }) => heads.delete(to))
  }
  for (const v of heads) {
    dfs(v)
  }
  for (const v of V) {
    dfs(v)
  }
  return stack
}
class G {
  constructor () {
    this.V = new Set()
    this.E = new Map()
  }

  setEdges (from, tos) {
    this.V.add(from)
    tos.forEach(({ to, w }) => this.V.add(to))
    this.E.set(from, tos)
  }
}
function solve ({ g, vToWeight }) {
  const stack = topologicalSort(g)
  console.log('ordering', stack.join(''))
  stack.forEach(v => {
    const edges = g.E.get(v)
    if (!edges) { return }
    const newval = Math.max(
      vToWeight.get(v),
      ...edges.map(({ to, w }) => vToWeight.get(to) + w)
    )
    console.log('setting best for', v, edges.map(({ to, w }) =>  [vToWeight.get(to), w].join('+') ))
    vToWeight.set(v, newval)
  })
  return vToWeight
}
function demo () {
  const g = new G ()
  g.setEdges(2, [{ to: 1, w: 5 }])
  g.setEdges(4, [{ to: 2, w: 2 }, { to: 3, w: 4 }])
  const vToWeight = new Map ([
    [1, 1],
    [2, 6],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4]
  ]) 
  return { g, vToWeight }
}
function demo2 () {
  const g = new G ()
  const addEdges = (i, ...tos) => {
    g.setEdges(i, tos.map(to => ({ to, w: 5 * i + to })))
  }
  addEdges(5,4,7)
  addEdges(7,1,2)
  addEdges(1,0)
  addEdges(0,6)
  const vToWeight = new Map ([...g.V].map(v => [v, 2**v])) 
  return { g, vToWeight }
}
function dump (map) {
  return [...map].map(([k, v])=> k+'->'+v)
}
console.log('----op\s sol----\n',dump(solve(demo())))
console.log('----that case---\n',dump(solve(demo2())))
```

Comment: Would this still work if you can't reach every node from the root node? By this I mean that when I create the graph, a node may only be connected by its directed edge to a node on the graph. For example, if you have 1 --5-> 2 --2-> 4, and then node 3 was 3 --4-> 4, you can't directly reach it from the first node.

Comment: This is slight matter. If you look at the topo (which you should copy from another source because i may have failed), i loop on every vertex, so it will order multiple graphs, should they be disconnected. While it is always better to have working code, the main idea is just to explore vertices in a way that de dependancies have already been explored

Answer (score 2):

The distance matrix (between all pairs of events = nodes) can by obtained in a iterative way, similar to the Floyd algorithm. Basically, iteratively:

```
T(x, y) = max (T(x,y), T(x, z) +T (z, y))
```

However, as mentioned by the OP in a comment, Floyd algorithm is O(n^3), which is too much for a value of `n` up to 10^5.

A key point is that no loop exists, and therefore a more efficient algorithm should exist.

A nice proposal was made by grodzi in their proposal: use a topologic sort of the Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).

I made an implementation in C++ according to this idea, with on main difference:

- I used a simple sort (from C++ library) for building the topological sorting. Doing it is simple and has a complexity of O(n logn). The dedicated method proposed by grodzi could be more efficient (seems O(n)). However, it is very easy to implement and such a complexity remains low.

After the topological sorting, we know that a given event only depends on the events before it. For this part, this insures a complexity of O(C), where C is the number of triples, i.e. the number of edges.

```
    #include    <iostream>
    #include    <vector>
    #include    <set>
    #include    <unordered_set> 
    #include    <algorithm>
    #include    <tuple>
    #include    <numeric>

    struct Triple {
        int event1;
        int event2;
        int days;
    };

    struct Pred {
        int pred;
        int days;
    };

    void print_result (const std::vector<int> &index, const std::vector<int> &times) {
        int n = times.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cout << index[i]+1 << " " << times[index[i]] << "\n";
        }
    }

    std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> ordering (int n, const std::vector<Triple> &triples) {
        std::vector<int> index(n);
        std::vector<int> times(n, 0);
        std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);

    //  Build predecessors matrix and sets
        std::vector<std::vector<Pred>> pred (n);
        std::vector<std::unordered_set<int>> set_pred (n);
        for (auto &triple: triples) {
                pred[triple.event2 - 1].emplace_back(Pred{triple.event1 - 1, triple.days});

                set_pred[triple.event2 - 1].insert(triple.event1 - 1);
        }

    //  Topological sort
        std::sort (index.begin(), index.end(), [&set_pred] (int &i, int &j) {return set_pred[j].find(i) != set_pred[j].end();});

    //  Iterative calculation of times of arrival
        for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            int ip = index[i];
            for (auto &p: pred[ip]) {
                    times[ip] = std::max(times[ip], times[p.pred] + p.days);
            }
        }

    //  Final sort, according to times of arrival
        std::sort (index.begin(), index.end(), [&times] (int &i, int &j) {return times[i] < times[j];});

        return {index, times};
    }

    int main() {
        int n_events = 4;
        std::vector<Triple> triples = {
            {1, 2, 5},
            {1, 3, 1},
            {3, 2, 6},
            {3, 4, 1}
        };

        std::vector<int> index(n_events);
        std::vector<int> times(n_events);
        std::tie (index, times) = ordering (n_events, triples);

        print_result (index, times);
    }
```

Result:

```
1 0
3 1
4 2
2 7
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Would the longest path with negative edges solution also work (as that would be easier for me to code)

Comment: Searching  the *shortest* paths with negative weights should work. Just pay attention to use an algorithm compatible with negative weights, as indicated by shasha in their answer. Ideally, you have to find an algorithm that uses the fact that there is no loop

Comment: while probably less efficient, upvoting for your sort simplicity

Comment: @grodzi Thank you. I may have misunderstood what you called a leaf. Is the the first or last arriving event? Besides, I did not know about the topologic sorting. Really interesting to benefit from the no-cycle characteristics

Comment: a leaf is a node which has no children / no dependancy. This would be the first arriving event. On my hand it didn't occur to me we could use a standard sort by simply using the definition and this is indeed way more straightforward